# Update Statement using Request Method Post

Tags: php, mysql

I've done a search related to 'update statement using form'.

Lots of post showed an update function using a form using `isset`

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { //process } else { //show form }
```

Does this mean that it is not possible to do update using this?

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { //process } else { //show form }
```

It seems so cause my update function doesn't work.

**Solved** : It works now. I added

```
<input type="hidden" name="contact_id" value="<?php echo $row["contact_id"]; ?>" />
```

before

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

in the form

```
<form method="post" action="update.php">
Username: <input type="text" name="contact_name" value="<?php echo $row["contact_name"]; ?>" />
Email: <input type="text" name="contact_number" value="<?php echo $row["contact_number"]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="contact_id" value="<?php echo $row["contact_id"]; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: If you want us to explain why it doesn't work, you'll need to post more code. What you posted **should** work.

Answer (score 0):

bith ways should work.

But what you should do first is :

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to make sure there is anything in the `$_POST` var before you do the 1st option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `REQUEST_METHOD` is always in uppercase. To test this, use `strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST'` and see if it works.